Does Google Maps Geocode API return detailed errors on why API calls may fail?
I discovered by chance today in our Google cloud console account that a significant percentage (43%) of all queries to the geocoding API are failing.

I have no idea why though.   When I run the tool on our site that uses them it seems to work.   So I wondered if there is detailed logging in the cloud console for this.
I went into the Log Explorer but it doesn't seem to show anything. Can these logging tools function on the geocoding API or is it just for specific APIs/services within their overall cloud setup?
Any clarification on how I can troubleshoot this would be most useful.
Just to clarify for anyone wondering; there is no tech support with the product on the standard version and they recommend asking here, although I guess you can say that they would say that.

For this kind of issue, it is best to reach out to the support of Google Maps platform.

You don't know the strings which are passed to the API, so it might be perfectly fine that the API is failing on so many requests.
